# Wandb ignores --configs flag when running training script

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, wandb

Running a script I want to specify what config YAML to use. [The documentation](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/config) states you can specify what configuration file to load using the `--configs` flag, however running

```
>>> python myscript.py --configs new-configs.yaml
```

on the following script

```
import wandb
wandb.init()
print(wandb.config)
```

I can see that the configuration contained in `config-defaults.yaml` is being loaded instead. Why is this happening?

#### Specs

```
MacOS 13.4.1 (Apple M1 chip)
python                        3.10.12
tensorflow-macos              2.12.0
tensorflow-metal              0.8.0
wandb                         0.15.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--configs flag` is used to specify a different configuration file other than the default `config-defaults.yaml`. However, it's important to note that the `--configs flag` should be used when running the `wandb` command, not when running your python script.
If you want to use a different configuration file when running your python script, you should load the configuration from the file manually in your script. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
python
import wandb
import yaml

# Load config from file
with open('new-configs.yaml') as file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(file)

# Initialize wandb with the loaded config
wandb.init(config=config)

print(wandb.config)
```

In this example, the configuration is loaded from `new-configs.yaml` using the `yaml` library, and then passed to `wandb.init()`.

If you still want to use the `--configs` flag, you should use it with the `wandb` command, like this:

```
bash
wandb --configs=new-configs.yaml
```

This will start a new run with the configuration from `new-configs.yaml`. However, this will not run your python script. If you want to run your script with this configuration, you should load the configuration from `wandb.config` in your script, like this:

```
python
import wandb

# Initialize wandb
wandb.init()

# Get the configuration
config = wandb.config

print(config)
```

In this example, the configuration is loaded from `wandb.config`, which is set by the wandb command with the --configs flag.

I hope this helps!